# Recreating or saving docker-compose files on ec2 reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

So I'm running two ec2 instances, both instantiated via command:

```
docker-machine create amazonec2 ....
```

Upon each instance I have to run:

```
docker-compose -f staging.yml up -d
```

in order to run the docker container inside of the ec2. This .yml file allows me to GET some data from RDS.

My issue is - every time the ec2 stops or reboots I have to run the docker-compose command again. How can I automate this process so that the docker will start this on its own every reboot?

I know you can write bash scripts in the Additional Details but I'm not given that option seeing as I'm creating the ec2 instance with docker-machine. Also I'm getting

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

When I try to ssh into the ec2 instance. I can use `docker-machine ssh` but I think that's only connecting me to the docker container.

I'm relatively new to AWS and Docker, any help (or clarification on what I have wrong) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron to start a script on startup
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already installed the docker engine and docker-compose in EC2. The problem is likely because it requires `sudo` access. This leaves us with two options:

1. Try running: `sudo docker-compose up` (`sudo docker-compose -f staging.yml up -d` in your case).
2. When I tried checking for the reason for permission, it was because of `docker.sock`. To solve that, run: `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Now coming to the point of, how do I give the right permissions on reboots - Use bash script or cloud-init, in the user-data of your EC2 instance:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
runcmd:
 - echo "For the first boot"

cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/sh
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
docker-compose up
--//--
```

Ideally, create an AMI with docker engine and docker-compose and launch EC2 instances from that AMI with the user-data; this way, you can easily create a target group later on.

One last point, if you are getting permission denied while `ssh` to the EC2 machine. Ensure the key-pair has the right permissions: `chmod 0400 <ec2-keypair>.pem`

For reference, please have a look at: https://github.com/addu390/licensing-as-a-platform (Note: the above reference link is my open-source project).